# HTML CSS: Button- Wrap Container Directly Around it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I wrap these boxes directly around the button? Right now I getting these horizontal long boxes spacing. I want to wrap directly around the bell button. This way user cannot utilize button without directly touching it. Using Chrome inspector, ctrl-shift-i

Currently using  text-align center, display:flex, align-items: center, justify-content: center, and its still not working. Red box below is ideal around

[image]

```css
.grid-container.toolsetbutton {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 100px);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 100px);
    grid-gap: 1px;
    padding: 0px;
    align-items: center;
}


.mdc-button.toolsetbutton {
    background:transparent;
    border:none;
}


.material-icons.mdc-button__icon.toolsetbutton {
    text-align: center;
    background:transparent;
    border:none;
    display:flex;
    border:none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="grid-container toolsetbutton">
  <button class="mdc-button toolsetbutton">
    <i class="material-icons mdc-button__icon toolsetbutton">notifications</i>
  </button>
  <button class="mdc-button toolsetbutton">
    <i class="material-icons mdc-button__icon toolsetbutton">delete</i>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: By "these boxes", do you mean the  grid outlines, the box model boxes (content, padding, border, margin), or the red outline?

Comment: the most detailed element would work, <i class="material-icons

Comment: it's tightly wrapped around the icon if you remove `display:flex`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if I'm understanding your intent correctly, just need to override the left/right margins with `auto` as shown. However, I'd advise you to not use your selectors in such a way as you do with all the `.blah.blah.toolsetbutton` stuff as the order of inception you're currently implementing will only become less performant and more difficult to maintain the more the it's propagated within a project.

Anyway, hope this helps, cheers!

```css
.grid-container.toolsetbutton {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 100px);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 100px);
    grid-gap: 1px;
    padding: 0px;
    align-items: center;
}


.mdc-button.toolsetbutton {
    background:transparent;    
    /*border:none; - removed so there's a visual aid of hit area */
        
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}


.material-icons.mdc-button__icon.toolsetbutton {
    text-align: center;
    background:transparent;
    border:none;
    display:flex;
    border:none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="grid-container toolsetbutton">
  <button class="mdc-button toolsetbutton">
    <i class="material-icons mdc-button__icon toolsetbutton">notifications</i>
  </button>
  <button class="mdc-button toolsetbutton">
    <i class="material-icons mdc-button__icon toolsetbutton">delete</i>
  </button>
</div>
```

So as requested, here's another approach more aligned with how I'd probably accomplish the same personally. Reasoning being that since `HTML` doesn't minify; well I'd rather write a tiny bit more CSS, and far less HTML over and over. This helps a lot with rendering speed and file sizes for less traffic on the wire. Anyway, a quick PoC learning example since we've all been there is below. Feel free to remove the tooltips and tinker obviously. Also I wouldn't use `grid` at all in this scenario in lieu of good 'ol [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Box_model) instead. Have a great weekend!

```css
.btn-grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 100px);
  grid-gap: 1px;
}

.btn-grid-container > button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.btn-grid-container > button:before {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  content: attr(data-icon);
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: transparent 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color .25s ease, background-color .25s ease, border-color .25s ease;
}

.btn-grid-container button:hover:before, .btn-grid-container button:focus:before {
  color: green;
  border-color: green;
  background-color: rgba(0,255,0,.1);  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="btn-grid-container">
  <button data-icon="&#xe7f4;" title="Notifications"></button>
  <button data-icon="&#xe872;" title="Delete"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! it works! feel free to write it in a simple coding convention answer also you recommended, still reading css articles and books all day, trying to learn